# Why am I getting undefined when I am trying to call my method?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

Beginner trying to relearn JS. Below is my following code. I've created a persons class with calculateAge method. When trying to pass my new const into my method I get a undefined, why is this the case? Please advise:

```
class Person6 {
    constructor (name, yearOfBirth, job) {
        this.name = name;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
        this.job = job;
    }
    
    // Functions can directly add to the class
    calculateAge() {
        var age = new Date().getFullYear - this.yearOfBirth;
        console.log(age);
    }
    
    // Static classes
    static greeting() {
        console.log('Hey there!');
    }
}

const quang6 = new Person6('Quang', 1994, 'IT');

Person6.greeting();

quang6.calculateAge();
```

Comment: getFullYear needs `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var age = new Date().getFullYear - this.yearOfBirth;
```

There's an issue with this line. The property `getFullYear` is a function that you need to call and since you're not doing so you end up with NaN. You need to add a `()` after the `.getFullYear`